# using replace on a result of ng-repeat to replace underscores with spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat="(name, value) in list.getIngredients()"` and in the controller template, I have:

`<span>{{name.replace("_", " ")}}</span><input name="{{name}}" value="{{value}} />`

What I want to do is to run the `String.replace()` function as above, but it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span>{{name.replace("_", " ");}}</span><input name="{{name}}" value="{{value}} />
```

you need the semicolon. >_>  When using Angular, you commonly don't need semi colons, but when you are dealing with javascript in this regard, you will need a semicolon, otherwise an error will occur.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna When doing replace with a literal, it will only replace the first occurrence.  You could build upon this a few ways.you could do something like: `name.split("_").join(" ");`. This is kind of dirt in my opinion.  You could also do: `name.replace(new RegExp("_", "g"), " ");`. This second option, passes in a regex, which will unlike the literal (replacing the first occurrence), would replace all.

Comment: Thanks. I tried something else. I used multiple .replace like {{name.replace("_", " ").replace("_", " ").replace("_", " ");}} and it solved my purpose.

Comment: @AmbujKhanna That is not a good design at all.  It is costly in terms of operations and string scans.  I would recommend against using that.